# Truth and Lier-teller Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic

I am really new on prolog, and I got the following question. It is actually an extra challenge class, but I have no idea to even start. I will be thankful for any ideas or small examples (better).

On an island in the Pacific there are two types of inhabitants: those who always speak the truth and those who always lie. Both, however, are profoundly aware of Propositional Calculus. Arriving at a crossroads you find one of these inhabitants but you do not know to which tribe he/she belongs. You also know that one of the ways will lead you safely to the hotel and another to a deadly gorge. Knowing that the Aboriginal will only answer YES or NO to a single question. Develop a program in PROLOG to find a propositional calculus sentence that allows you to choose the right way to return safely, regardless of whether the question is asked to an inhabitant of the tribe of liars or truth tellers.

Comment: You should try a Google search on "prolog logic puzzles" to see some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is the following :

```
% initialize which way is safe
isSafe(left).

% predicates for truth and lie tellers
truthTeller(X) :- X.
lieTeller(X) :- \+ X.
wouldTheOtherSay(X) :- truthTeller(lieTeller(X)).
```

Then all you have to ask is :

> ?- wouldTheOtherSay(isSafe(left)).

And this will always be a lie so if the answer is `yes` you should go right and *vice versa*.

---

### Edit

Here is another version :

```
% initialize which way is safe
isSafe(left).

% initialize who is a truth-teller & who is a lie-teller
truthTeller(dean).
lieTeller(sean).

% a truth-teller would say Y is true if Y is true
% a lie-teller would say Y is true if Y is false
wouldSay(X,Y) :- 
   truthTeller(X),Y;
   lieTeller(X),\+Y.

% a truth-teller would say the other would say Y is true if Y is false
% a lie-teller would lie and say the other would say Y is true if Y is false
wouldTheOtherSay(X,Y) :-
   truthTeller(X),lieTeller(Z),wouldSay(Z,Y);
   lieTeller(X),truthTeller(Z),wouldSay(Z,\+Y).

% this is so you don't get true then false -- we keep the first result
onceWouldTheOtherSay(X,Y) :- once(wouldTheOtherSay(X,Y)).
```

Then :

```
?- onceWouldTheOtherSay(sean,isSafe(left)).
?- onceWouldTheOtherSay(dean,isSafe(left)).
```

will give you `no`, and :

```
?- onceWouldTheOtherSay(sean,isSafe(right)).
?- onceWouldTheOtherSay(dean,isSafe(right)).
```

will give you `yes`.

Still, as `lie*truth` equals `truth*lie` equals `lie`, you should go the other way around.